# Highlighting rows in excel based on the start of postcodes

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a data file that includes the postcodes of supporters and I need to highlight the rows that contain a number of them. At the moment I have the following code;

```
Sub ScotTest()

Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
    iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "H").Text Like "TD" & "*" Then
            Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Whilst this highlights the correct rows with all postcodes beginning with TD I now need to also highlight postcodes beginning with KY and KA.

Thanks

Comment: You could use conditional formatting for this. Do you need VBA?

Comment: If you want to stick with VBA, just add a couple of ORs in that line.

Answer (score 4):

Simply adding an OR to your IF should do the trick :)

```
Sub ScotTest()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "H").Text Like "TD" & "*" OR _
           Cells(i, "H").Text Like "KY" & "*" OR _
           Cells(i, "H").Text Like "KA" & "*" Then
            Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Select Case` is another option along these lines.

Answer (score 4):

[Conditional Formatting](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html) would be an easier way to achieve this, but if you are trying to learn VBA, I respect that and can suggest an approach:

If you are only going to have a couple cases, then you could add it inline:

```
If (Cells(i, "H").Text Like "TD*") OR (Cells(i, "H").Text Like "KY*") OR (Cells(i, "H").Text Like "KA*") Then
```

A more elegant solution would be to use a Regex and test them all together

```
With Regex
    .Pattern = "(AS|KY|AB).*"
End With

If Regex.Test(Cells(i, "H").Text) Then
```

Make sure to include the VBA regex library in your project so that it works

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-regex/

https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: `RegEx` would be my personal favorite way to approach this

Answer (score 2):

As some people already proposed, you might do this using conditional formatting (based on a formula). The following formula (based on the assumption that the cell `A1` contains a postal code) might do the trick:

```
=OR(LEFT(A1;2)="TD";LEFT(A1;2)="KY";LEFT(A1;2)="KA")
```